# What is "Synthetic Network" in Network Science?

Tags: graph-theory, network-modeling

I checked out several articles, books available, but didn't find what exactly is a "synthetic network".

Comment: Typical usage in network science is not really a technical term, it's just the English word "synthetic," meaning not from a natural source, but rather made by some artificial process (as in the answer below), often times in order to mimic some properties of natural sources. So: made by some model or artificial process, rather than coming from a "real" data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer if you don't explain more precisely the context, but I think it would be networks generated using some random model such as [Watts-Strogatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model)'s, [Barabasi-Albert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model)'s, etc.

Comment: Thanks..I understand it now..
The confusion arised because the term is not defined in Network science i.e. it is a informal terminology

Comment: Yes. You can also find the expression "artificial network", meaning the same thing.